# Associated indexes of two list

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have two list :

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string>()
{
    "xxxxxxxx_green_xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx_yellow_xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx_blue_xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx_white_xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
};

List<string> List2 = new List<string>()
{
    "yyyyyyyy_blue_yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "yyyyyyyy_green_yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "yyyyyyyy_white_yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "yyyyyyyy_yellow_yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
};
```

Where `x` and `y` is a random char.

I want to create a dictionary where values with the same color are associated

Expected output :

```
Dictionary<string, string> ExpectedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"xxxxxxxx_green_xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyy_green_yyyyyyyyyyyyy"},
    {"xxxxxxxx_yellow_xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyy_yellow_yyyyyyyyyyyyy"},
    {"xxxxxxxx_blue_xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyy_blue_yyyyyyyyyyyyy"},
    {"xxxxxxxx_white_xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyy_white_yyyyyyyyyyyyy"}
};
```

What is the best way to do this ? With linq ? Or with a regex?

Comment: Do you have only a distinct color value per list ? I mean now 2 green records for example ?

Comment: Yes only a distinct color per list

Comment: You may find the below answer helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq's `Join` and `String.Split`:

```
var ExpectedDictionary = (from l1 in List1
                          join l2 in List2
                          on l1.Split('_')[1] equals l2.Split('_')[1]
                          select new
                          {
                              V1 = l1,
                              V2 = l2
                          }).ToDictionary(x => x.V1, x => x.V2);
```

### Safety First Approach:

To handle invalid input, you can use regex:

```
private string getColor(string value)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(value, "_(.*?)_");

    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach(Group group in match.Groups)
        {
            if (counter++ == 0)
                continue;

            string color = group.Value;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(color))
                return color.ToLower();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then we need to change the query to be:

```
var ExpectedDictionary = (from l1 in List1
                          join l2 in List2
                          on getColor(l1) equals getColor(l2)
                          select new
                          {
                              V1 = l1,
                              V2 = l2
                          }).ToDictionary(x => x.V1, x => x.V2);
```

Using Lambda Syntax:

```
var ExpectedDictionary2 = List1.Join(List2, l1 => getColor(l1),
                                            l2 => getColor(l2),
                                            (l1, l2) => new { V1 = l1, V2 = l2 })
                               .ToDictionary(x => x.V1, x => x.V2);
```

Comment: If there is underline in random chars will have problem but good enough

Comment: @MichaelMao Added an approach to capture what is between two `_`. Otherwise for complex scenarios, the OP needs clear requirements for what to do in case of conflicts.

Comment: Thx how to write the join with lambda expression ?

Comment: @Azerty123 Check the edited answer. Please mark this answer as accepted if you find it helpful.